# Chef server will not start - Starting chef-server In 16011 Fail

Tags: chef-infra

olrHow do I deal with the below?

```
/etc/init.d/chef-server-webui start
 * Starting chef-server-webui
 ~ In 15468
  ...fail!

root@li409-115:/etc/init.d# /etc/init.d/chef-server start
 * Starting chef-server
 ~ In 16011
  ...fail!
```

There is nothing in the logs files in /var/log/chef/server.log or
server-webui.log

starting chef client and solr works.

So... how to resolve?

Comment: It would be good to know the environment you are installing on and the steps you followed.

Answer (score 8):

Workaround:

1. Make sure the chef-server-webui service is stopped: sudo /etc/init.d/chef-server-webui stop
2. Start the web UI process manually (it will log to the console, not the log file):        sudo /usr/sbin/chef-server-webui
3. When the process is up ("Successfully bound to port 4040"), stop it with Ctrl-C
4. Start the chef-server-webui service: sudo /etc/init.d/chef-server-webui start

The service should start now and log to /var/log/chef/server-webui.log.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at this link and it worked for me https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-3204
I executed below commands on my chef server VM (ubuntu 12.04). You might have to sudo su. I think my problem was couchdb was not running. Please note the sequence is important

- /etc/init.d/couchdb stop
- /etc/init.d/couchdb start
- /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server stop
- /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server start
- /etc/init.d/chef-solr stop
- /etc/init.d/chef-solr start
- /etc/init.d/chef-expander stop
- /etc/init.d/chef-expander start
- /etc/init.d/chef-server stop
- /etc/init.d/chef-server start
- /etc/init.d/chef-server-webui stop
- /etc/init.d/chef-server-webui start